# Upload de arquivos com Java

Tags: java, java-ee, upload, file-upload, servlet

Bom dia! Estava tentando fazer o upload de arquivos, onde tenho uma página web que faz uma requisição pra minha servlet. No form da página tenho um input do tipo file e outro do tipo text. O modo de codificação desse form está como "multipart/form-data". A minha grande dificuldade é que todos os exemplos que eu vi de utilização da package org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload tem o seguinte trecho de código:

```
    try
    { 
        // Analisar a solicitação para obter itens de arquivo.
        List <FileItem>fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

        // Processar os itens de arquivos enviados
        Iterator <FileItem> i = fileItems.iterator();
```

Porém no meu caso ocorre o erro da imagem abaixo:

[image: erro_eclipse]

> The method parseRequest(RequestContext) in the type FileUploadBase is not applicable for the arguments (HttpServletRequest)

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão ou já teve o mesmo problema e puder me ajudar fico agradecido. Ou se tiver algum outro método mais recomendável de fazer uploads de arquivos em java estou aceitando dicas, pois é a primeira vez que estou estudando a respeito disso.

Abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O parseRequest [(RequestContext ctx)](http://ommons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html#parseRequest(org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext)) espera que a `RequestContext`  seja um argumento, mas o argumento aprovado é instância de `HttpServletRequest`

Use [ServletRequestContext](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html#parseRequest(org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext)) para criar uma RequestContext  instância da seguinte forma.

```
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466194/error-in-file-uploading-code

Comment: Isso funcionou, muito obrigado pela resposta, eu estava quebrando a cabeça há um tempão :)

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

O método da função que você esta chamando esta esperando um objeto de outro tipo.

Tente fazer de acordo com o exemplo abaixo:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        /*Obtem o caminho relatorio da pasta img*/
        String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("img")+ File.separator;

        File files = new File(path);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        /*Mostra o arquivo que está na pasta img onde foi realizado o upload*/
        for (String file : files.list()) {
            File f = new File(path + file);
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```